# How do I get my input boxes to line up (3x3) instead of (1x9) on HTML?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I'm writing a code that allows you to run 3 separate spring simulations where you can adjust the mass, spring constant and damping coefficient independently with input boxes. They all come out one after another like
box
box
box
box
.
.
.
box
9 times. how can I shift them to have them 3 by 3. 3 on the left, 3 in the middle and, 3 on the right?
box                              box                              box
box                              box                              box
box                              box                              box

```
<html>
<header>
    <title>Diaz's Harmonic Oscillator</title>
</header>
<body>
    <style>
    .HarmonicOscillator-input {
        font-family: inherit;
        font-size: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px 7px 7px 7px;
    }
    
    .HarmonicOscillator-inputSmall { width: 5em; }
    .HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered { text-align: center; }
    </style>
    <div>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1500" height="500"></canvas>
        <button type = "button" id="myButton" onclick="resetButton()" 40px >Reset</button>

    </div>
    <div class="HarmonicOscillator">
        <canvas class="HarmonicOscillator-canvas"></canvas>
        
        <p class="HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered">Top Mass<br>
            <input class="HarmonicOscillator-input HarmonicOscillator-inputSmall HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered" 
                type="number" id="HarmonicOscillator-topMass" min="1" max="10000" step="1" pattern="\d*"
            >
        </p>
        
        <p class="HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered">Top Spring constant<br>
            <input class="HarmonicOscillator-input HarmonicOscillator-inputSmall HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered" 
                type="number" id="HarmonicOscillator-topSpringConstant" name="topSpringConstant" min="1" max="10000" step="1" pattern="\d*"
            >
        </p>

        <p class="HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered">Top Damping Coefficient<br>
            <input class="HarmonicOscillator-input HarmonicOscillator-inputSmall HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered" 
                type="number" id="HarmonicOscillator-topDampCoefficient" name="topDampCoefficient" min="0" max="10000" step="1" pattern="\d*"
            >
        </p>
        <p class="HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered">Mass<br>
            <input class="HarmonicOscillator-input HarmonicOscillator-inputSmall HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered" 
                type="number" id="HarmonicOscillator-mass" min="1" max="10000" step="1" pattern="\d*"
            >
        </p>
        <p class="HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered">Spring constant<br>
            <input class="HarmonicOscillator-input HarmonicOscillator-inputSmall HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered" 
                type="number" id="HarmonicOscillator-springConstant" name="springConstant" min="1" max="10000" step="1" pattern="\d*"
            >
        </p>

        <p class="HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered">Damping Coefficient<br>
            <input class="HarmonicOscillator-input HarmonicOscillator-inputSmall HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered" 
                type="number" id="HarmonicOscillator-dampCoefficient" name="dampCoefficient" min="0" max="10000" step="1" pattern="\d*"
            >
        </p>
        
        <p class="HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered">Bottom Mass<br>
            <input class="HarmonicOscillator-input HarmonicOscillator-inputSmall HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered" 
                type="number" id="HarmonicOscillator-bottomMass" min="1" max="10000" step="1" pattern="\d*"
            >
        </p>
        <p class="HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered">Bottom Spring constant<br>
            <input class="HarmonicOscillator-input HarmonicOscillator-inputSmall HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered" 
                type="number" id="HarmonicOscillator-bottomSpringConstant" name="bottomSpringConstant" min="1" max="10000" step="1" pattern="\d*"
            >
        </p>

        <p class="HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered">Bottom Damping Coefficient<br>
            <input class="HarmonicOscillator-input HarmonicOscillator-inputSmall HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered" 
                type="number" id="HarmonicOscillator-bottomDampCoefficient" name="bottomDampCoefficient" min="0" max="10000" step="1" pattern="\d*"
            >
        </p>
    </div>


    <script src="sandBox.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `display:inline-block` to the `p` tags that contain the inputs, then insert linebreaks when needed.

```css
p.HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<header>
  <title>Diaz's Harmonic Oscillator</title>
</header>

<body>
  <style>
    .HarmonicOscillator-input {
      font-family: inherit;
      font-size: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 10px 7px 7px 7px;
    }
    
    .HarmonicOscillator-inputSmall {
      width: 5em;
    }
    
    .HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered {
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
  <div>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1500" height="500"></canvas>
    <button type="button" id="myButton" onclick="resetButton()" 40px>Reset</button>

  </div>
  <div class="HarmonicOscillator">
    <canvas class="HarmonicOscillator-canvas"></canvas>
    <br/>
    <p class="HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered">Top Mass<br>
      <input class="HarmonicOscillator-input HarmonicOscillator-inputSmall HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered" type="number" id="HarmonicOscillator-topMass" min="1" max="10000" step="1" pattern="\d*">
    </p>

    <p class="HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered">Top Spring constant<br>
      <input class="HarmonicOscillator-input HarmonicOscillator-inputSmall HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered" type="number" id="HarmonicOscillator-topSpringConstant" name="topSpringConstant" min="1" max="10000" step="1" pattern="\d*">
    </p>

    <p class="HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered">Top Damping Coefficient<br>
      <input class="HarmonicOscillator-input HarmonicOscillator-inputSmall HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered" type="number" id="HarmonicOscillator-topDampCoefficient" name="topDampCoefficient" min="0" max="10000" step="1" pattern="\d*">
    </p>
    <br/>
    <p class="HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered">Mass<br>
      <input class="HarmonicOscillator-input HarmonicOscillator-inputSmall HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered" type="number" id="HarmonicOscillator-mass" min="1" max="10000" step="1" pattern="\d*">
    </p>
    <p class="HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered">Spring constant<br>
      <input class="HarmonicOscillator-input HarmonicOscillator-inputSmall HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered" type="number" id="HarmonicOscillator-springConstant" name="springConstant" min="1" max="10000" step="1" pattern="\d*">
    </p>

    <p class="HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered">Damping Coefficient<br>
      <input class="HarmonicOscillator-input HarmonicOscillator-inputSmall HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered" type="number" id="HarmonicOscillator-dampCoefficient" name="dampCoefficient" min="0" max="10000" step="1" pattern="\d*">
    </p><br/>

    <p class="HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered">Bottom Mass<br>
      <input class="HarmonicOscillator-input HarmonicOscillator-inputSmall HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered" type="number" id="HarmonicOscillator-bottomMass" min="1" max="10000" step="1" pattern="\d*">
    </p>
    <p class="HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered">Bottom Spring constant<br>
      <input class="HarmonicOscillator-input HarmonicOscillator-inputSmall HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered" type="number" id="HarmonicOscillator-bottomSpringConstant" name="bottomSpringConstant" min="1" max="10000" step="1" pattern="\d*">
    </p>

    <p class="HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered">Bottom Damping Coefficient<br>
      <input class="HarmonicOscillator-input HarmonicOscillator-inputSmall HarmonicOscillator-isTextCentered" type="number" id="HarmonicOscillator-bottomDampCoefficient" name="bottomDampCoefficient" min="0" max="10000" step="1" pattern="\d*">
    </p>
  </div>


  <script src="sandBox.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Any change you can provide an example? Not entirely sure what you mean.

Comment: @buenosdiaz Have you tried running my code snippet?